# The definition of Pisot number

Tags: number-theory

A Pisot number is  an algebraic integer $>1 $ and all of whose conjugates have modulus $<1$.   and I want to ask that is the polynomial is unique? I mean that the degree of the polynomial is minimal.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what you're asking here because the definition of the Galois conjugates of a Pisot number $\alpha$ are defined to be the other roots of the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ (with the required properties on the moduli).

The minimal polynomial of a Pisot number $\alpha$ is a monic polynomial of least degree. The minimal polynomial of any algebraic integer is unique, and irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ (hence of minimal degree).